# Scale an irregular shape to irregular bounds

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I am attempting to make a reusuable, XAML, icon. It is composed of three parts.

Background, Bezel and Graphic Path objects. The shape is of a rectangle with the top right corner cut off, the bezel is same shape with the middle cut out and a margin of 1.

I need the graphic path to fit inside of this with a slight margin.

I would like it to be intelligent enough to scale itself to fit within the confines of the bezel regardless of it's shape. Like ClipToBounds only I don't want the graphic to clip - I would like it to scale.

I initially thought setting the Margin would work, however, setting the Margin of the graphic is based on a Rectangle and not the irregular shape of the bezel; so graphics with a more rectangular shape are often touching or too close to the right-side cut off of the bezel.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might achieve this kind of ScaleToBounds behavior?

**EDIT:**

Please see attached pictures for an example of the problem. Both graphics are contained inside a ViewBox with a Margin. The circular graphic is the ideal margin I would like to see around the graphic. The rectangular graphic is too close to the bezel - I would like to have graphics such as the rectangular graphic scale themselves down slightly so they fit within the bezel with some margin.

[rectangular graphic http://s11.postimage.org/a5v05ve2n/rectangular.png](http://s11.postimage.org/a5v05ve2n/rectangular.png)
[circular graphic http://s11.postimage.org/do7029eyn/circular.png](http://s11.postimage.org/do7029eyn/circular.png)

Comment: Judging by your description, have you tried nesting it in a ViewBox with Stretch=Fill?

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, graphics are nested inside of a ViewBox. I have added some pictures and additional information to the post. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, ok. but you don't want to clip it? Is there concern of having the margin on all four sides equal? This looks like it comes down to the 'ol square peg vs. round hole analogy.. :/

Comment: @ChrisW. Ideally I would like to have a bounding box that is the same shape as the background. When the bounding box detects that the graphic is out of bounds it would set the width/height of the graphic to a smaller size so that it was no longer out of bounds and would fit within the confines of the bezel.